# Structured programs combining cardio and weights

Tags: programs

I had a personal trainer for a while who was good but it was too expensive for me at the moment.

I was taking short breaks in between supersets.

I can't seem to find an online program which combines cardio and weight training.

I have no problem paying for anything but all the ones I see all seem focused on weight training alone.

Looked at six pack and Athlean-X but I found both very poor.

I want to leave the gym covered in sweat as this has really improves my well being but I cannot find an online course that combines the two.

Can anyone point me to a structured plan combining cardio and weight training ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81467/discussion-between-alec-and-dagda1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is something that smashes the two worlds of cardio and weightlifting together in one. In the Crossfit world, this is a Metcon. I know it as [Circuit Training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_training).

Circuit training is basically doing a series of related workouts in a specific order. You don't do them with particularly heavy weight because the point is to just keep going from one workout to another. The total workout lasts maybe 20-30 minutes, and various plans typically include both weight lifting and cardio. Though despite the length, it is a very intense workout! If you aren't sweating by the end of it, then you simply didn't go hard enough. Though always be cautious that form doesn't break down. It is common for people to get a little carried away and walk out with an injury.

There are a growing crop of gyms (at least in the United States) like [Orange Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangetheory_Fitness) which do these kind of workout. They only do classes which makes them cheaper than hiring a personal trainer for yourself. There are other gyms that advertise them as "boot camp" style classes. There is of course also Crossfit, but I find them to be *really* expensive.

If you'd prefer your own, you can just search "circuit training programs" or "Boot camp workout" and [you'll find all sorts](https://www.military.com/military-fitness/workouts/circuit-training). They can be rather difficult to do in a gym, however. If you do them in a commercial gym, then you have to be courteous of the other members. You don't want to be "that guy" that takes up all the equipment to complete their circuit. Though if you can find a good spot to do it, then go for it.

Answer (score 2):

To sweat more and get more cardio into your workouts. Just look at "Home cardio workouts" incorporate these into your weight training as supersets. Make sure on the weights side of things you always get that one last rep you struggle with. This greatly increases the stress your body undergoes and follows up with sweat as expected.

The problem is people weight train for size and mass, people use cardio for weight loss and shredding but doing lots of cardio to where you're sweating buckets is not good to be mixed with weight training as it really kills your energy and your progress. People tend to only do enough cardio to burn enough fat whilst maintaining as much weight as they can.